# Outline on border-box [behaviour inconsistent on Chrome]

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, outline

Given a `div` with `tabindex="0"` I get this weird *outline* behaviour on Firefox and Chrome.

```css
.inner {
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.context {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.custom_outline:focus {outline: 3px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div class="context" tabindex="0">
  <h1>Wrong outline on Firefox</h1>
  <h2>... but on Chrome is even WORSE</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div><div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="context custom_outline" tabindex="0">
  <h1>Wrong outline on Firefox</h1>
  <h2>... but on Chrome is BETTER if I set an explicit outline</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div><div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### By default:

- **Firefox**'s outline wraps the `div`, *including the negative margins* that are inner to it; this draws a rectangle.
  [image]
- **Chrome**'s outline wraps the `div`, *including the negative margins* that are inner to it; this *draws a polygon* that deviates just around the negative margin.
  [image]

### Setting an explicit outline:

- **Firefox**'s outline wraps the `div`, *including the negative margins* that are inner to it; this draws a rectangle. **[Nothing changed. Consistent behaviour, at least]**
- **Chrome**'s outline wraps the `div`, ***not*** considering the negative margins that are inner to it; this *draws a rectangle* that ignores the negative margin.
  [image]

Why this inconsistent behaviour? What triggers the difference in Chrome? Who is respecting more the W3C specifications?

The result I want to achieve is the last case of Chrome, with the outline **wrapping the `div` and ignoring the negative margin** (considering just the *border-box*, like is happening with the `background-origin` property)

How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The specs don't define exactly how outlines are drawn except that they don't affect layout, and that they *may* be non-rectangular. What triggers the difference in Chrome is probably down to how it implements the default outline in the first place — you can tell that it looks like nothing that can be accomplished using pure CSS.

To achieve your desired result, you can cheat by adding the outline to an absolutely positioned `::before` pseudo-element on focus (and disabling the outline on the element itself):

```css
.inner {
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.context {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.custom_outline:focus {
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}

.custom_outline:focus::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="context" tabindex="0">
  <h1>Default outline</h1>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div><div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="context custom_outline" tabindex="0">
  <h1>Custom outline</h1>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div><div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really nice solution :) ... **but**, cause of the `z-index:-1` (that is mandatory), the top outline is covered from the adjacent `div.header` above the `div.context` (see modified Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ushwmcs0/). This is not happening when the outline is directly on `div.context` without pseudo-element. How could that be fixed?

Comment: @Kamafeather: If you can afford to use `pointer-events: none` (I'm not sure how well it is supported by browsers), replace `z-index: -1` with that.

Answer (score 0):

chrome draws edges of area than are being focused :

You may reset `outline` to `none` and use `box-shadow` instead.

```css
.inner {
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.context {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.custom_outline:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="context custom_outline" tabindex="0">
  <h1>box-shadow outlining Firefox</h1>
  <h2>... but on Chrome reset outline to none too</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div>
    <div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

test defaut behavior of chrome: see it drawing focusable area's edges

```css
.inner {
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.context {
  margin-right: 60%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.context:hover {
  outline-color: red;
  /* color  reset , if style is reset, behavior is reset too*/
}
h2:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 105%;/* outside the box */
}
```

```html
<div class="context" tabindex="0">
  <h1>no outline on Firefox</h1>
  <h2>... but on Chrome ...</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div>
    <div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where FF will include everything in a box:

```css
.inner {
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.context {
  margin-right: 60%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.context:focus {
  outline: solid 3px blue;
}
h2:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 105%;/* outside the box */
}
```

```html
<div class="context" tabindex="0">
  <h1>Wrong outline on Firefox</h1>
  <h2>... but on Chrome is even WORSE</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="inner">Foo</div><div class="inner">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```